# How do I import FullCalendar on my React Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fullcalendar, babeljs

I am getting `TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function` error when I am trying `import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'`  on my project which is configured with webpack.
I tried manipulating webpack.config.dev.js but couldn't figure out how to implement it in a right way.
whenever I am trying to import any of the component from @fullcalendar it is throwing me the webpack error

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
    import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

export default {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
    entry: [
        // must be first entry to properly set public path
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/webpack-public-path',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js') // Defining path seems necessary for this to work consistently on Windows machines.
    ],
    target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
            __DEV__: true
        }),
        // new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: './src/scripts', to: 'assets' } ]),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
        //   template: 'src/index.ejs',
        //   minify: {
        //     removeComments: true,
        //     collapseWhitespace: true
        //   },
        //   inject: true
        // }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: false,
            debug: true,
            noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
            options: {
                sassLoader: {
                    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')]
                },
                context: '/',
                postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader'] },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
            { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
            { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'] }
        ]
    }
};
```

`Package.json File:`

```
{
    "name": "MedFix",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Project Tracking and Management",
    "engines": {
        "npm": ">=3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src",
        "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
        "test": "mocha -w tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
        "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
        "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
        "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
        "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
        "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
        "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist build:html",
        "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
        "analyze-bundle": "babel-node ./tools/analyzeBundle.js"
    },
    "author": "789",
    "license": "123",
    "dependencies": {
        "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/react": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.1.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "4.0.1",
        "auth0-js": "7.6.1",
        "auto-bind": "1.2.0",
        "awesomplete": "1.1.2",
        "axios": "0.16.2",
        "babel-helper-bindify-decorators": "6.24.1",
        "block-ui": "2.70.1",
        "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "3.0.3",
        "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
        "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
        "color": "2.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
        "country-currency-map": "1.0.9",
        "country-data": "0.0.31",
        "country-list": "2.1.0",
        "currency-codes": "1.5.0",
        "currency-symbol-map": "4.0.4",
        "download-url-file": "0.0.2",
        "downloadjs": "1.4.7",
        "enzyme": "2.6.0",
        "expect": "1.20.2",
        "express": "4.15.3",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "fullcalendar": "3.10.0",
        "geo-tz": "4.0.2",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "jquery-validation": "1.16.0",
        "jsdom": "11.1.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.7.0",
        "mocha": "3.4.2",
        "mock-local-storage": "1.0.3",
        "moment": "2.18.1",
        "moment-timezone": "0.5.21",
        "npm": "4.6.1",
        "object-assign": "4.1.0",
        "opentok-react": "0.7.0",
        "path": "0.12.7",
        "react": "15.4.1",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
        "react-autobind": "1.0.6",
        "react-autocomplete": "1.8.1",
        "react-autosize-textarea": "0.4.8",
        "react-autosuggest": "9.3.2",
        "react-big-calendar": "0.14.0",
        "react-block-ui": "1.1.1",
        "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "3.4.0",
        "react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker": "2.0.4",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "4.0.3",
        "react-bootstrap-time-picker": "1.0.3",
        "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "3.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap-validation": "0.1.11",
        "react-bootstrap-xeditable": "0.2.7",
        "react-calendar": "2.14.0",
        "react-checkbox-group": "4.0.1",
        "react-ckeditor-component": "1.0.7",
        "react-confirm-alert": "2.0.2",
        "react-cookie-consent": "1.7.0",
        "react-credit-card-input": "1.0.9",
        "react-currency-input": "1.3.4",
        "react-datepicker": "1.5.0",
        "react-device-detect": "1.6.2",
        "react-display-name": "0.2.4",
        "react-dom": "15.4.1",
        "react-dropzone": "4.2.7",
        "react-edit-inline": "1.0.8",
        "react-escape-html": "1.0.5",
        "react-geocode": "0.1.2",
        "react-google-autocomplete": "1.0.18",
        "react-html-parser": "2.0.2",
        "react-idle": "3.0.0",
        "react-imask": "3.4.0",
        "react-input-mask": "0.9.1",
        "react-js-pagination": "3.0.2",
        "react-ladda": "5.0.7",
        "react-loadable": "5.3.1",
        "react-loading": "2.0.2",
        "react-maskedinput": "4.0.1",
        "react-modal-bootstrap": "1.1.1",
        "react-moment": "0.7.0",
        "react-notification-system": "0.2.15",
        "react-paginate": "5.0.0",
        "react-pdf": "3.0.5",
        "react-pull-to-refresh": "1.1.2",
        "react-redux": "5.0.1",
        "react-redux-toastr": "7.2.6",
        "react-reorder": "3.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-responsive-modal": "2.0.1",
        "react-router": "3.0.0",
        "react-router-redux": "4.0.7",
        "react-rte": "0.11.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
        "react-scrollable-anchor": "0.6.1",
        "react-select": "1.0.0-rc.4",
        "react-signature-pad-wrapper": "0.0.9",
        "react-star-rating-component": "1.4.1",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "2.6.3",
        "react-switch": "3.0.4",
        "react-tag-input": "5.0.2",
        "react-tagsinput": "3.17.0",
        "react-text-mask": "5.1.0",
        "react-textarea-count": "1.0.3",
        "react-times": "3.0.0",
        "react-timezone": "2.1.0",
        "react-toastify": "4.0.1",
        "react-tooltip": "3.6.1",
        "react-typeahead": "2.0.0-alpha.8",
        "react-validation": "3.0.7",
        "react-x-editable": "0.0.5-beta",
        "reactstrap": "6.0.1",
        "recharts": "1.0.1",
        "redux": "3.6.0",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
        "sortablejs": "1.7.0",
        "sweetalert": "1.1.3",
        "text-mask-addons": "3.7.1",
        "timezoner": "0.2.0",
        "toastr": "2.1.2",
        "video-react": "0.13.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "autoprefixer": "6.5.4",
        "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
        "babel-core": "6.20.0",
        "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.20.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.3.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.16.0",
        "browser-sync": "2.18.5",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "compression": "1.6.2",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "1.1.3",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
        "css-loader": "0.26.1",
        "datatables.net": "1.10.16",
        "enzyme": "2.6.0",
        "express": "4.15.3",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
        "file-loader": "0.9.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "json-loader": "0.5.4",
        "mockdate": "2.0.1",
        "node-sass": "4.12.0",
        "npm-run-all": "3.1.2",
        "open": "0.0.5",
        "opn-cli": "^3.1.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "1.2.1",
        "prompt": "1.0.0",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
        "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.4",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "replace": "0.3.0",
        "riek": "1.1.0",
        "rimraf": "2.5.4",
        "sass-loader": "6.0.2",
        "style-loader": "0.13.1",
        "url-loader": "0.5.7",
        "webpack": "2.2.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.1.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.17.1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react",
            "stage-1"
        ],
        "env": {
            "development": {
                "presets": [
                    "env",
                    "react-hmre"
                ]
            },
            "production": {
                "presets": [
                    [
                        "env",
                        {
                            "es2015": {
                                "modules": false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "plugins": [
                    "transform-react-constant-elements",
                    "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
                ]
            },
            "test": {
                "presets": [
                    "env"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react ?

Comment: @ADyson yes I have tried that one but i wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: why not? What went wrong? I've seen other questions on here where people have been using it successfully. It seems like the most obvious way to integrate it, since all the connection between react and fullCalendar is already done for you.

Comment: can you refer a link to the posts? I couldn't find any, I have tried multiple sources. I did exactly the same as official Docs. I think webpack is causing the problem.

Comment: Well I'm not sure the posts I mentioned would actually show you the details of how to do it. What I meant was that I have seen questions where people are clearly using it successfully, they were just having a more specific question about usage of fullCalendar within that context. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272750/how-to-populate-modal-on-event-click or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289522/fullcalendar-doesnt-adjust-the-height-of-cells-with-customised-events-when-firs are recent examples.

Comment: But again, if you have a problem with that integration, it would make sense to post the code and configuration you used and the errors/unexpected behaviour you experience when you try. It could always be a separate question, if you prefer to have that as a second option to doing it the way you're trying in this one.