# How do I Implement React Fullcalender on React 15(15.4.1) with @fullcalendar/react library?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I posted a question regarding fullcalendar having issue with my webpack.
[[How do I import FullCalendar on my React Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351367/how-do-i-import-fullcalendar-on-my-react-project.][1])
After a long inspection I found out that @fullcalendar/react doens't work on React 15.4.1 which on which my project is built. I created a boiler plate code for react 15 and react 16. The same code works on 16 However it doesn't work on 15. When I try to upgrade my project it throws multiple error. How can I implement Fullcalender in my react 15.4.1 project without jquery(which is working)? or is there any way I can upgrade my project to react 16 without breaking the code? I did upgrade the code using `npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install` command which updates all the packages from my package.json file to latest version. I want to update my packages to the lastest version to which they are compatible for my code.

`npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install`

````
  "name": "medfix",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^4.1.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}```

Doesn't works on this version.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351367/how-do-i-import-fullcalendar-on-my-react-project


I'm getting error of 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined at eval (eval at <anonymous>
````

Comment: you'll have to be more specific about the errors you're experiencing. We can't guess what messages you get.

Comment: @ADyson I installed prop-types:15.7.2, react-router:16.8.6, react:16.8.6, react-redux:7.0.3. Made Change from React.createClass to 'createReactClass' after getting different errors like, can't find the shape property of undefined, _react3.default.createClass isn't a function which get resoved after installing updating above packages. now I am getting ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous>```

Comment: Please use the "edit" button under your question to add further information like this, and format it so it is clear and readable. Error info etc does not belong in the comments. Thanks